# Why isn't doxygen putting any external doc links in the generated doc? It is reading the tagfile

Tags: doxygen

I have a library documented with Doxygen. It's doxyFile contains

```
GENERATE_TAGFILE       = build/doc/mylib/mylib.tag
```

Doxygen generates the documentation and tagfile without complaint.

I have a package also documented with Doxygen. I want the package documentation to refer to the library documentation. The package doxyFile contains

```
TAGFILES               = build/doc/mylib/mylib.tag=../../mylib/html
```

Doxygen reports

```
Reading and parsing tag files
Reading tag file `build/doc/mylib/mylib.tag', location `../../mylib/html'...
```

Apart from some warnings about duplicate anchors

```
/Users/mark/Projects/github/Foo/build/doc-x/mylib/mylib.tag:800: warning: Duplicate anchor vdiparam found
```

Doxygen completes without a problem. However the generated package doc does not include any references to the external library documentation.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to put explicit links in the package documentation? If so, how?

What I want is to have an entry in the first level of the left-pane treeview of the package docs that links to the library doc's main page.

Comment: When still relevant could you retry with the current doxygen version (1.8.15) and if the problem is still present show the differences in your Doxyfile compared to the default (as off 1.8.15 possible with: doxygen -x Doxyfile) and also a small example showing the problem?

Comment: @msc were you able to fix this?

Comment: No I was not. It is very frustrating. I have put explicit links in the package docs for the time being. Note for @albert, I'm currently using Doxygen 1.8.17.  I have a move coming up. After that I will attempt to create a small example.

Comment: I'll wait for the example, hopefully the move is to doxygen 1.8.20 and this will solve the problem.